# How would I align these controls to the left this?

Tags: java, swing

This is what it outputs :

[image: This is what it outputs :]

I want to align 'Imprimante : MonImprimante' on the far left
as well as the 3 check boxes.

You can find the code relevant to the things I want aligned by searching *** with ctrl-f

This is my code :
`

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

public class ImprimanteWindow extends JFrame{

   //Declares the panels used to place the controls.
private JPanel JPanelBtn;
private JPanel JPanelChk;
private JPanel JPanelRad;
private JPanel JPanelDrpChk;
private JPanel JPanelWrap;
private JPanel JPanelSuperWrap;
private String[] QltImpression = { "Haute", "Medium", "Bas"};

public ImprimanteWindow(){


    //Initialise the panels
    JPanelBtn = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1, 10, 10));
    JPanelChk = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    JPanelRad = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    JPanelDrpChk = new JPanel();
    JPanelWrap = new JPanel(); //used to put the other panels inside
    JPanelSuperWrap = new JPanel();  //used to put everything in 1 big panel

            //Initialise the buttons and add them to the button Panel
    JPanelBtn.add(new JButton("Ok"));
    JPanelBtn.add(new JButton("Annuler"));
    JPanelBtn.add(new JButton("Paramètre"));
    JPanelBtn.add(new JButton("Aide"));
    this.add("East", JPanelBtn);

            //***I want to align this to the far left 
            //adds the check boxes to the checkbox panel
    JPanelChk.add(new JCheckBox("Image"));
    JPanelChk.add(new JCheckBox("Texte"));
    JPanelChk.add(new JCheckBox("Code"));

            ////adds the radio buttons to the radiobutton panel
    JPanelRad.add(new JRadioButton("Selection"));
    JPanelRad.add(new JRadioButton("Tous"));
    JPanelRad.add(new JRadioButton("Applet"));

            //***I want to align this to the far left 
            //adds the label to the top section of the panel
    JPanelSuperWrap.add(new JLabel("Imprimante : MonImprimante"));

            //adds the 2 panels and the slider to the middle section
    JPanelWrap.add(JPanelChk);
    JPanelWrap.add(JPanelRad);
    JPanelWrap.add(new JSlider());
    JPanelSuperWrap.add(JPanelWrap);    

            //adds a label, a combobox and a checkbox to the bottom.
    JPanelDrpChk.add(new JLabel("Qualite de l'impression :"));
    JPanelDrpChk.add(new JComboBox(QltImpression));
    JPanelDrpChk.add(new JCheckBox("Imprimer dans un fichier"));
    JPanelSuperWrap.add(JPanelDrpChk);
    this.add(JPanelSuperWrap);

    this.pack();

    this.setSize(500,170);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.validate();
}


public static void main(String args[]){
    ImprimanteWindow gui = new ImprimanteWindow();

}
}`
```

Any help in placing the controls on my gui would be greatly appreachiated!
Thank you guys so much!

Comment: I think You will need to use a different layout manager than `GridLayout`, If this question isn't answered after I get back form lunch, I will post some code.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making life harder with nested panels that have hard set layouts and then wrappers that don't. If you're going to take explicit control at the microlevel and have a specific display requirement (like your label case), you should have explicit layouts in `JPanelWrap` and `JPanelSuperWrap`.

Also, use layouts that communicate your intent better. Why are you using 3x1 [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) in the nested components when a [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) expresses your intent better? You're doing the Swing equivalent of HTML nested `<table>` layouts that way. You can make the inner panels use Boxes with Filler since they're simple columns, and use a 2x2 GridBagLayout for `JPanelSuperWrap`, with `JPanelBtn` taking 2 rows.

You'll probably also want better names than for what those panels actually are, and you really should consider encapsulating this View into subcomponents that are instantiated from `ImprimanteWindow`. In other words, take the pieces like `JPanelBtn` piece and put it into another class that semantically defines what that grouping is, like `SelectionChoices`, then define a method on that class that returns you a JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you add a JCheckBox, JLabel, or JRadioButton (denoted as `j` from here on out), try calling `j.setHorizontalTextAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);`.  I suspect this may not work, however, because you are using `GridLayout`, which is a fairly inflexible layout.

It would be better, IHMO, if you use `GridBagLayout` in the `JPanels` for these components and used `GridBagConstraints` to tell the layout how to align those components when you add them to their respective panels.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you just do this

```
    JPanel scope = new JPanel();
scope.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Scope"));
scope.setLayout(new BoxLayout(scope,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
scope.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
```